# Git local repository commits export

Tags: git, export, repository, local

I have, probably, a stupid question..
I'm gonna use local repository for my project.
Will it be possible to export whole repository with all the commit history to the remote one (for example, i'll create it in a half of a year). 
Will all the commits, for example,appear in the commit history in github or other remote git platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will push all history of commit to the remote branch.

just add remote branch and push

`git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git`

And then push via following command

`git push <remote_branch> <local_branch>`